# Заменть на заглавные буквы после тире

Tags: javascript

Требуется, чтобы после тире была заглавная буква. Подскажите, где ошибка? если выводить в `console.log("ля-ля".replace)`, то все норм, а через переменную не получается.

```js
var style = "font-size, background-color, text-align"; 
 
function camelCase(css){
  let style = css;
  for(var i = 0; i  < style.length; i++){   
    if (style[i] == "-"){
      style[i+1] = style[i+1].toUpperCase();     
      console.log(style[i+1]);
    }
  }   
  return style;
}

console.log(camelCase(style));
```

Comment: var style = "font-size, background-color, text-align"; 
 
   function camelCase(css){
   let style = css;
   let letter;
   for(var i = 0; i  < style.length; i++){   
    if (style[i] == "-"){
     letter = = style[i+1].toUpperCase();
     style[i+1] = letter;     
     console.log(style[i+1]);
    }
   }   
   return style;
   }
   
   console.log(camelCase(style));
    
 Было изначально так...

Comment: а могло бы быть [так (regex101)](https://regex101.com/r/r6I9JR/1)